# How do I import users from a CSV file for free?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

Rather than having to enter a long list of new users manually, is there a free extension I can use to add new users from a CSV file?

Comment: Your question should be connected with this one: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15347/adding-multiple-users-in-joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Users Importer for J2XML" is free and enables you to import users from a CSV file:

http://extensions.joomla.org/browse/new/extension/migration-a-conversion/users-import-a-export/users-importer-for-j2xml